# Enterprise portal development for AX 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, enterprise-portal

to work in the right way for the EP development do I need to have visual studio and the AOS installed on the same machines?

Thanks,

Luca Ganz

Answer (score 0):

To do EP development, you need Visual Studio installed on the client machine, along with Visual Studio tools for Dynamics AX. Visual studio uses the client application's COM connector to interface with AX and get the AOT and metadata. Whether or not the AOS and client are installed on the same machine depends on your installation, but in a typical production or development installation, these will be on different boxes.

You can read more about installing VS for AX here: [Install Visual Studio Tools [AX 2012]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309576.aspx)

Here is the TechNet section on installing Enterprise Portal: [Install Enterprise Portal [AX 2012]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731804.aspx)